# Rails3 association and accepts_nested_attributes_for failing when validation of user_id on

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, associations, nested-attributes

I am following the Rails Tutorial doing a little project for myself and then try to progress.

Well I am facing a problem for which I found the solution, but I'll really appreciate any thoughts and opinions because to make it work I have to disable a validation in an association.

The context is as follow : the application (big name for what it does actually...) has users to track their weight. I would like that when a user sign up, he/she enters a first measure on the go.

So here are the simplified models:

User.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :email, :name, :password, :password_confirmation, :measures_attributes

  has_secure_password

  has_many :measures, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :measures

  # here goes validations before_save, etc. taken from the Rails Tutorial
end
```

Measure.rb

```
class Measure < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :weight
  belongs_to :user

  # This is kind where the problem is...
  # If I deactivate the validation for user_id everyhing goes fine
  validates :user_id, presence: true
  validates :weight, presence: true, numericality: { greater_than: 0 }

  default_scope order: 'measures.created_at ASC'
end
```

Here is the Users controller

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

  # GET /users/new
  def new
    @user = User.new
    @user.measures.build
  end

  # POST /users
  def create

    @user = User.new(params[:user])

    if @user.save
      sign_in @user
      flash[:success] = "Hi #{@user.name}. Welcome !"
      redirect_to @user
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

end
```

Here is the form partial for the user :

```
<%= form_for(user) do |user_form| %>
  <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: user_form.object %>

  <%= render 'users/fields', user_builder: user_form %>

  <%= user_form.fields_for :measures do |measure_fields| %>
    <%= render 'measures/fields', measure_builder: measure_fields, full: true %>
  <% end %>

  <%= user_form.submit submit_text, class: 'btn btn-large btn-primary' %>
<% end %>
```

And even when I fill the form correctly, I get this error :

```
* Measures user can't be blank
```

The only way I found to make it work is to get rid of the :user_id validation for presence in the Measure model. I want to emphasize that when this validation is off, the user is saved, the measure is saved and correctly associated with the newly created user.

Am I doing something wrong ? Is the :user_id presence validation in the Measure model really useful (it is in the Rails Tutorial and it makes perfectly sense for me) ? If yes why is the Measure validation failing when it is on ?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: In your `measures/fields` partial are you providing a hidden field for `user_id` to make sure it gets carried through the process?

Comment: Ah, no I don't ! But the user_id is not accessible and at this stage it doesn't exits as we are in the User creation process. 

I'll try this anyway, thanks

Comment: Ok as the :user_id is not accessible I get the error

    Can't mass-assign protected attributes: user_id

Comment: Yeah I figured. You've set accessible attributes on Measure only to include `weight`. This is the right behaviour

Comment: What is the right behavior ? The fact that :user_id is not accessible or the fact that the accepts_nested_attributes_for doesn't work in my case ?

Comment: Probably both, but the former for sure. I'm guessing something's going on in the background without the hidden field since, as you say, the record is saved properly when the validation is removed. It's probably that the user_id is being assigned after the validation stage, which means it's absent when the validation is run

Comment: Yes, but it is strange. This means that the validation of both models is done before the parent model (user) is saved, but the child model is saved correctly (having the :user_id) after that if the validation pass on both (:user_id validation off)

I tried other things like saving the user first then creating the measure if it is correct, saving the measure and deleting the user in case the measure is invalid.

But it is very complicated to manage error messages : if both user and measure are invalid.

I thought about a transaction but no luck so far.

What I want to do seems so simple !

Comment: You could try `validates :user` instead of `user_id`. Then it might work out that the two are associated in memory even though the User hasn't been saved yet.

Comment: Thanks !! This one does the trick.

Actually it prevents a measure to be created directly without the user, doesn't show error messages for the :user_id, and save both when all is correct.

So the code should be 
    validates :user, presence: true

Comment: OK I've added it as an answer so that you can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try validates `:user` instead of `user_id`. Then it might work out that the two are associated in memory even though the User hasn't been saved yet.

Comment: This works perfectly, error messages included.
Thanks a lot for the help

Answer (score 0):

I think I may have found an error in your code that would cause the error you're seeing.

In your new controller you specifically create an association:

```
@user.measures.build
```

In your create controller, you create a new element based on the fields that were passed in.

```
@user = User.new(params[:user])
```

There are some cases where the associated element will be dropped. I can't remember if this happens by default if it doesn't validate or if there was an option you need to set to make it drop.

I think you may need to add

```
@user.measure.build if @user.measures.empty?
```

in your `create` controller `else` clause before `render :new`.

I don't know if you're actually hitting this problem, but it would explain why the association to your `User` wasn't set.

Comment: Thanks. I think this wasn't really the problem, but what you explain makes sense so I added the line as I don't see how it can do any harm.